# Regular Expression Help (not working for all cases)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I basically have a stream of data that I am parsing and this is the typical format of it:

Format 1

```
07/11 04:05P 00:01:04 T204  *** P003 003                    P003           5019207185 7666
```

Sometimes the data format gets tweaked and it comes in this format:

Format 2

```
07/11 04:05P 00
:01:04 T204  *** P003 003                    P003                          5019207185 7666
```

Now the same regular expression that works for format 1 won't work on format 2. Can anyone provide an explanation? Keep in mind I am new to regex so it might just be something really silly.

This is my regular expression:

```
\s([\d/]+)\s([\d:AP]+)\s([\d:]+)\s([\dT]+)\s+([*]+)\s([PXTI\d]+)\s+([\d]+)?\s+([\da-zA-Z]+)\s+([\d]+)\s([\d]+)\s+$
```

I forgot to mention, I am looking for the *** in the data stream.

Comment: You should go for a regex tool which shows you where and why it stops matching...nobody is doing this by hand : )

Comment: [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Comment: You could ask yourself, if your regex works for format 1, but not format 2, is there a way to get format 2 to look like format 1?

Comment: That's the bad part i can't control the format, its coming from a live system, no control over it =/.

Comment: Yes, but you still have it in a string, which you can control.  If a `\n` is causing your regex to break, all you have to do is remove all `\n` characters before running your regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must replace this part `\s([\d:]+)\s` by `\s(\d+\s*:\d+:\d+)\s`

An example pattern that match the two formats:

```
(\d{2}/\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}[AP])\s(\d{2}\s*:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(T\d+)\s+(\*+)\s+([PXTI]\d+)\s+([\d]+)?\s+(?i)([a-z]\d+)\s+(\d+)\s(\d+)
```

Comment: can you expand on what you mean exactly?

Comment: @user1772052: look at the `[\d:]` near the begining.

Comment: Yea i tried that, it wont solve the issue, i can't parse format 1 or format 2 if i replace it how u told me to.

Comment: But that still requires whitespace at the beginning and end, and neither of the examples have that. Also, this allows *any* whitespace where the line breaks in Format 2. If I understand correctly, only a newline should be matched. Unless the regex needs to allow trailing whitespace on the first line?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main difference between the inputs is that one has a line break after the "00". I believe your regex will have to allow for the possibility of a whitespace character between the digit and the colon. That would need to be in around the third "stanza", here: `([\d:]+)`.

I will say that that seems like a very non-standard place to break from the format, and if at all possible, it might be worth mentioning it to whoever provides the data, to see if you can get it consistent. Having line breaks in place of spaces wouldn't kill you because your regex already uses a macro that would recognize those.

Comment: Ya its hard to ask them as i am capturing data from a system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you have it working even on the first one. It looks like the second match group, `([\d:AP]+)`, is intended to match "04:05P" (or whatever time), but since you start with **\s** and the string doesn't begin with whitespace, the first match group matches the time, and it's downhill from there. Also, you're requiring the string to end in whitespace, but neither of your examples does. I think what you want is to make the whitespace at the beginning and end optional:

```
\s*([\d/]+)\s([\d:AP]+)\s([\d:]+)\s([\dT]+)\s+([*]+)\s([PXTI\d]+)\s+([\d]+)?\s+([\da-zA-Z]+)\s+([\d]+)\s([\d]+)\s*$
```

BTW, is Format 2 intended to be broken up into two lines? If so, you want to optionally match the newline:

```
\s*([\d/]+)\s([\d:AP]+)\s([\d]+\n?[\d:]+)\s([\dT]+)\s+([*]+)\s([PXTI\d]+)\s+([\d]+)?\s+([\da-zA-Z]+)\s+([\d]+)\s([\d]+)\s*$
```

That's assuming the newline always comes in exactly the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Your capture group that captures the time;

```
 ([\d:]+)
```

...can be extended to allow whitespace (also line feed)

```
([\d\s:]+)
```

To make the parsing slightly more robust, you may want to restrict the date to 8 or 9 matches;

```
 ([\d\s:]{8,9})
```

Note that the resulting capture group will still contain the linefeed, so you may need to strip that from the captured time before using it.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comments, I would suggest having one regex for one format, not multiple regexes for multiple formats.  Normalize all the strings you receive into the same format, if you can.  Given your two examples, you can definitely do this.

What are you finding? `\s*`

What are you replacing it with?  (a single space).

Follow this example: [Regex find and replace](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace)

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "\s*", " ");
```

Then, run your original regex on `output`.